# Why do I get a message saying I've built all the floors in Tiny Tower Vegas?

Tags: tiny-tower-vegas

Haven't reached the maximum number of floors, I only have 104 floors, but the game won't let me add more. When I try to add another floor (I have enough coins) I get a message saying I've built all the floors.

Answer (score 1):

I played for a while (gave up ~4 years ago) and I recall someone saying 104 is the maximum number of floors.

[This source](https://www.reddit.com/r/TinyTowerVegas/comments/2fq6nb/is_104_the_max_number_of_floors_you_can_have/) corroborates that, but it's been a while since I've played and this source is 7 years old...